# Malformed web.config file aspNetCore node causing issues

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

**Using IIS 10 and .NET Core 2.0**

The web.config was generated from a new .NET Core MVC project.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>      
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MvcMovie.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With it in this configuration I can't open the configuration editor in IIS and gives a 500.19 error:

```
Config Source:
   -1: 
    0:
```

If I remove the `<aspNetCore />` node, it will open in the configuration editor in IIS but will give a 500.21 error:

```
Handler "aspNetCore" has a bad module "AspNetCoreModule" in its module list
```

What would I do to get about fixing this?

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? The first config file that is auto generated in a new net core mvc project is correct, and the one that needs to be deployed with it to IIS. Did you install the net core hosting package for IIS on your server?

Comment: I'm getting a 500.19 server error with the message: The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid and the config source I have detailed above. This is simply the out of the box install of IIS.

Comment: You **must** install the net core hosting package in order to deploy net core projects to IIS. They will not work out of the box. https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all

Comment: I installed the latest non preview version of 2.0 and I'm still getting a 500 error. I've restarted my IIS Server, do I need to restart it on a service level at all?

Comment: Everytime I've installed that package I've had to do a full server reboot.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you haven't installed the IIS Hosting bundle.

Go here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all

Click the version of ".NET Core Runtime" that you need, then download the "Hosting Bundle Installer" under "Windows".

Comment: I installed the latest non preview version of 2.0 and I'm still getting an error. I've restarted my IIS Server, do I need to restart it on a service level at all?

Comment: Did you add the `aspNetCore` line back after installing? You need it.

Comment: Yep, I redeployed it as well and have rebooted the server. Is there a more verbose error logging I could toggle?

Comment: Anything in the Event Viewer? Does the site actually work, or is it just the Configuration Editor? Your web.config looks almost exactly like mine (which works). Make sure there are no stray, odd characters anywhere in the file. Maybe copy and paste the relevant text into a new file and save it and delete the old one, just in case.

Comment: Yes it seems to be a bug with .NET Core `No service for type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet' has been registered`

Comment: 10x @GabrielLuci, it actually worked for me.
I've re-published the project, there weren't any change on the web.config but i believe that IIS now know's how to work with it :)